# Какой фрэймворк использовать, чтобы можно было создавать jpg картинки с возможностью попиксельного редактирования/кодирования?

Tags: java, изображения, framework, edit

Нужен фреймворк для работы с картинками, в первую очередь с расширением jpg.

И для редактирования и для создания с нуля.

Необходима возможность попиксельно ставить, заменять нужные цвета.

Работаю через язык программирования Java.

Вопрос: Какие фрэймворки максимально или на все 100% подходят для выполнения выше описанного?

Comment: Ваша задача бьётся на три - 1.декомпрессор - 2.редактор (bitmap) - 3.компрессор. 1 и 3 одной библиотекой, думаю, найти можно. 2- вероятнее всего будет нейтивная работа с канвасом или битмапом или массивом RGB. Думаю задачу лучше упростить разбив на две - кодек отдельно - изображение - отдельно.

Comment: Хорошо, ваш коммент несет пользу, это бесспорно. А насчет пунктов 1 и 3, я вроде кое что нашел, я на правильном пути с вашей точки зрения? вот ссылка на это кое что https://www.slideshare.net/Vishubanga/image-compression-and-decompression-system